# netcore ODBC connection to informix database on centos

Tags: odbc, informix

I can access informix database through odbc configuration under windows10 environment. But if you put it on Linux, you can't access it.

Linux above I through unixODBC, ODBC.ini and OdbCinst.ini configuration, with ISQL and IUSQL can test through. I don't know what the problem is. Hope the great God can give a solution, thank you

Comment: It would help if you can include the error you are getting. If you can connect with UnixODBC ISQL, .NETCore should be able to connect too, but you may need to adjust the UNICODE value in your ODBC ini file.
You may want to try the latest version of CSDK (4.50.FC4W1). It contains it's own .NET Core provider (Informix.Net.Core.dll) so no there is need to use ODBC.  More info here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.cliapinode.doc/ids_net_core.htm

Comment: First thanks @jsagrera

Both ISQL and IPSQL are testable. I have tried unicode UCS-4, UCS-2, and UCS-UTF8. Program ERROR message: System. Data. The Odbc. OdbcException x80131937 (0) : ERROR [H] [

ERROR [H] [

Comment: The fact that you get a truncated error message (there should be a lot more than just 'ERROR[H]' indicates that value for UNICODE in the ODBCINI is wrong. I believe .NET CORE uses UCS-2.  Try with that and see what error you get.